# XSLT To Remove Elements of an XML

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have the following XML;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataroot generated="2015-01-07T10:49:16" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
<order job_id="S026500-1" site_code="DG" replace="">
<ORDERPK>3</ORDERPK>
<Replace>true</Replace>
<job_description>TESTING</job_description>
<order_qty>20000</order_qty>
<finishing_style>PB</finishing_style>
<depth>10</depth>
<width>8</width>
<cover_pagination>4</cover_pagination>
<text_pagination>24</text_pagination>
<delivery_commence_date>19/12/2014</delivery_commence_date>
<delivery_complete_date>19/12/2014</delivery_complete_date>
<job_site>DG</job_site>
<managing_printer>DG</managing_printer>
<is_managing_printer>True</is_managing_printer>
</order>
<master_version>
<ORDER>1</ORDER>
<version_id></version_id>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>true</version_common>
<version_finished>false</version_finished>
<version_description>Common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>176262</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>10</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
<ORDER>2</ORDER>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>TRUE</version_common>
<version_finished>FALSE</version_finished>
<version_description>Common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>1900</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
<master_version>
<ORDER>3</ORDER>
<version_code>COMM</version_code>
<version_common>true</version_common>
<version_finished>false</version_finished>
<version_description>common</version_description>
<version_nett_qty>20000</version_nett_qty>
<version_special_qty>0</version_special_qty>
</master_version>
```

I'd like to remove all of the "master_version" tables where the Order isn't equal to ORDERPK in the "order" table. Is there anyone who could help me with an XSLT for this? I haven't got any code to post and I'm completely stumped on how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with the template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

you can add templates to delete nodes, e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="master_version[not(ORDER = //order/ORDERPK)]"/>
```

will delete the `master_version` elements where the `ORDER` element value is not found in an `order/ORDERPK` element.

Comment: Pipped! I prefer this one to mine. The eliminating non-matching elements technique provides much less verbose code than outputting matching ones.

Comment: Honestly I have to agree, it does seem simpler to me, I'm only really just learning XML, but I do appreciate both answers, so thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

Use an identity template to return everything untouched, and provide an override template for the `<master_version>` element to only return the matching order:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        IDENTITY
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        OVERRIDES
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
        <xsl:template match="master_version">
                <xsl:if test="ORDER = /dataroot/order/ORDERPK">
                        <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates />
                        </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```